# Frequency with fft.complexForward

Tags: java, fft, nan, complex-numbers, pitch

I want to calculate the fundamental frequency with autocorrelation and I found this code:

```
public double calculateFFT(double[] signal)

     {
      final int mNumberOfFFTPoints =1024;

      double[] magnitude = new double[mNumberOfFFTPoints/2];
      DoubleFFT_1D fft = new DoubleFFT_1D(mNumberOfFFTPoints);
      double[] fftData = new double[mNumberOfFFTPoints*2];
      double max_index=-1;
      double max_magnitude=-1;


      final float sampleRate=44100;
      double frequency;

      for (int i=0;i<mNumberOfFFTPoints;i++){

       fftData[2 * i] = signal[i]; 
       fftData[2 * i + 1] = 0;

       fft.complexForward(fftData);
      }

      for(int i = 0; i < mNumberOfFFTPoints/2; i++){

       magnitude[i]=Math.sqrt((fftData[2*i] * fftData[2*i]) + (fftData[2*i + 1] * fftData[2*i + 1]));

       if (max_magnitude<magnitude[i]){
        max_magnitude=magnitude[i];
        max_index=i;
       }
      }


      return frequency=sampleRate*(double)max_index/(double)mNumberOfFFTPoints;

 }
```

I analyzed that fftData before "fft.complexForward(fftData);" contains some values, but after this operation ("fft.complexForward(fftData)") contains NaN. 
Why? 
Can someone help me, please?
Thanks

Comment: Hello. Have you found the answer for this question yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outputs of FFT are complex numbers. The method complex forward calculates the FFT of the fftData and puts it back in fftData. The even indices are real parts of the FFT while the odd indices are the imaginary parts. Since this code is calculating the magnitudes in the end, there's no need for a for loop. So instead of,

```
for (int i=0;i<mNumberOfFFTPoints;i++){
fftData[2 * i] = signal[i]; 
fftData[2 * i + 1] = 0;
fft.complexForward(fftData);
}
```

Just write :

```
fft.complexForward(fftData);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the complexForward method but I believe that it's taking a 1024 point FFT, and you need the give a signal of length 1024, however since this loop takes fft's one after another after the first time the method executes; you're giving the function a signal that's 2048 points long, and the output becomes NaN(because the method excepts 1024 points). Without the loop there shouldn't be any NaN values.

Comment: I changed my code, but I continue to get NaN values, also if input values aren't NaN.